# Condicão com Click

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um Quiz com 4 respostas/botões,e com itens, que só são ativados se forem clicados,um deles funciona da seguinte maneira:Se quiser utilizar ele tem que o ativar antes de responder,pois ele funciona como um escudo,sendo assim, após ele estar ativo,a pessoa responde,se responder errado este item entrará em funcionamento e fará um Refresh no form,caso a resposta esteja certa,o item não faz nada. Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer a condicão para os botões,esssas condições button.click não funcionam.

```
 private void gunaCirclePictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Evento do tal item 
    {            
        if (button1.Click || button2.Click|| button3.Click) // Esses são os botões correspondentes as respostas erradas,ou seja só se um desses botões forem clicados é que fará o refresh do form
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente seu código está dizendo que se `gunaCirclePictureBox2` for clicado ele executará esse `if`, o que não é o que quer. Pelo jeito que você descreveu seria melhor criar um evento de click pra cada botão errado e ele chamar o método `Refresh`. Criando um método `GameOver` você poderia chamá-lo sempre que uma resposta for errada, apenas atribuindo ao clique do botão posteriormente.